# how to setup a procss/thread when use joblib parallel

Tags: joblib

here is common usage for joblib parallel

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def is_memmap(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, np.memmap)

Parallel(n_jobs=2, max_nbytes=1e6)(
    delayed(is_memmap)(np.ones(int(i))) for i in [1e2, 1e4, 1e6])
```

I need use a connection to my database in function: **is_memmap**, but this connection can't be shared between workers, so I have to open a connection when I enter it and close it when exit it:

```
def is_memmap(obj):
    # open connection
    # do something
    # close connection 
    return isinstance(obj, np.memmap)
```

**since joblib will create a worker pool and reuse it. Can I open a  connection for each thread/process  when joblib create the work pool?.**

So I don't have to open/close connection many times.

here is what I want:

```
def is_memmap(obj):
    # **connection is already open, I can use it with a magic varaible**
    # do something
    # conection will close after all work is done. no need close it here.
    return isinstance(obj, np.memmap)
```